# Find the amount of ID that has same price in entire table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table looked like below:

```
id    price
1       10
1       10
1       10
2       30
2       33
2       30
3       15
3       15 
3       15
```

How can I determine the number of ids that has the same price(such that their price stays constant) throughout the table? In the table above, the answer will be 2, for id=1 and id=3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) first and then count values with `1`:

```
a = df.groupby('id')['price'].nunique()
print (a)
id
1    1
2    2
3    1
Name: price, dtype: int64

print ((a == 1).sum())
2

#if need ids
print (a.index[a == 1].tolist())
[1, 3]
```

Comment: Welcome back to you too ;)

Comment: @Dark - Thank you ;)